# How to assign values from a local csv file to variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to read a csv file stored locally on my machine, and assign each value to a javascript variable.

- The number of values/variables is known (less than 30) and can be hardcoded
- I plan to use these vars to set some parameters
- (edit) JQuery is allowed

How do I go about doing this in JS?

Comment: For a start, you'll need a http server running on your computer, which can server the resource (csv file) you need, with CORS enabled, unless it also serves the webpage that is reading the csv file

Comment: Try something like this http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=6UGbrFxKBOM